# Applications of stochastic processes

Tags: soft-question, stochastic-processes

What are stochastic processes? What are they used for? How can they be applied to real concepts? What is an example of a "stochastic process" problem?

Comment: What background reading have you done in probability? Have you at least looked online at references such as Wikipedia for a sense of the concept of stochastic process? The questions being asked seem too broad, almost like asking "what's a derivative? How can it be applied to real concepts? What is an example of a derivative problem?"

Comment: @KCd Do you know of a good source for learning more about the background of the concept? I looked at the Wikipedia page and did not really understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Stochastic processes are used everywhere - queuing theory (applied to communication networks among other things), statistical signal processing (adaptive filtering, estimation problems, RADAR, etc.), operations research, finance (see Shreve's Mathematical Finance text), etc.

A stochastic process is simply a collection of random variables. Usually these random variables obey some sort of structural relation - for example, they may be related in time (time series) or space (such as wireless signal strengths in space), or through something like a Markov random field (used in machine learning).

Answer (score 1):

A stochastic process in loose terms is dynamics resulting from probabilistic fluctuations (like the spread of a disease in a population). They are used throughout condensed matter physics to get accurate descriptions of phenomena; they are used in stock market predictions; they are used in traffic simulations; they are used in epidemic modeling. A very easy example to understand is the susceptible-infected-recovered (SIR) model of disease transfer. I did a project for a course last year on epidemic models and comparing the deterministic and stochastic projections. You can find the PDF [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5ofk1mpb13wbz5/AMATH_777_Cameron_Williams.pdf).

Comment: Could you please include a link to the PDF?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to figure out a way to do that. Haha.

Comment: There doesn't need to be any dynamics - a collection consisting of a single random variable or a collection of unrelated random variables is technically a stochastic process.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a Dropbox link? @CameronWilliams

Comment: Oh duh. I am not sure why I didn't think of Dropbox. @Batman you're right. I just like thinking of stochastic processes in terms of dynamics (since that's often where they occur).

Comment: @user112829 I have added the PDF. I take a lot of pride in the project even if it's not that impressive to some. It was one of the highlights of my master's degree (along with a project I did on the Haar measure on locally compact groups). I had a lot of fun with it. Hopefully it is a good read for you.

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to reading it.

Answer (score 0):

A stochastic process is an ensemble of deterministic waveforms, or realizations, where each waveform is a function of time. Just as the random variable $X$ maps each outcome $\omega$ in sample space $\mathcal{S}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the random process $X(t)$ maps each outcome to a deterministic function of time. If time is fixed, say, at $t_1$, the random process $X(t_1)$ is nothing but a random variable.

Stochastic processes find tremendous applications in Finance and Electrical Engineering, esp. in Communications and Signal Processing. Noise in communication receivers, which is modeled as additive white Gaussian noise process, is one example of such a stochastic process.